# Symfony : get same function in all arrays

Tags: php, sql, arrays, symfony, doctrine

I have these two queries :

```
$queryHisto = $repo->createQueryBuilder('h');
    $queryHisto->select('h', 'c')
               ->join('h.season', 's', 'WITH', 'h.player = ?1')
               ->join('h.club', 'c')
               ->orderBy('s.year', 'ASC')
               ->setParameters(['1' => $id]);
    $playerInfo = $queryHisto->getQuery()->getResult();

    

    $queryDivision =$manager->createQuery('SELECT c FROM App\Entity\Classement c JOIN c.clubHistos h WHERE h.club = :club AND c.season = :season');
    $queryDivision->setParameters(['club' => $playerInfo[0]->getClub(), 'season' => $playerInfo[0]->getSeason()]);
    $division = $queryDivision->getResult();
```

Written like this, my second query will only get the club and season of the first array of the first query because of `playerInfo[0]`. How can I get the `getClub()` and `getSeason()` functions from all the arrays of my first query ?

Comment: Research how to do a `WHERE ... IN` query with the builder and pass it mapped arrays (use `array_map` on `$playerInfo` for both parameters).

Comment: Though, this should probably be combined into a single query, since the data is clearly connected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand why I need an `IN` statement in my query ? The query fetches what I want when I try it in phpMyAdmin. As for the array_map how do I implement it in my setParameters() function ?

Comment: You need `IN` if you want to match multiple values (which is what I understood you want to achieve). There's nothing special about using `array_map` for the parameters. You just map the entire array twice, first time calling `getClub()` on all elements, the second time calling `getSeason()`.

Comment: I am rather new to Symfony but when I do `$qc = array_map("getClub()", $playerInfo)` it gives me an error : expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'getClub()' not found or invalid function name

Comment: Yeah, you can't do it like that (regardless of Symfony). Write an anonymous function and call the method on the element inside it.

Comment: I did `public function fetchClub() {$q = new ClubHisto(); $q->getClub(); return ;
    }` outside of my route and then in my `setParameters(['club' => array_map("fetchClub", $playerInfo)])`. It still gives me the same error

Comment: Yes, because that's not how you specify class methods to be used as callbacks. An anonymous function would be the simplest approach. See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php#96564) for an example.

Comment: No reason to create a new instance in the callback. You're supposed to use the instances from the result. Take a look at the example again, it defines a parameter for the callback, that will be the element of the current array iteration. Just call your method on it.

Comment: So like so : `array_map(function($club) { return $club['club']->getClub();}, $playerInfo)` ? But it gives me an error saying I cannot use object of type App\Entity\Historique as array.

Comment: Of course you can't. `$club` is not an array, it's an object. In the example array access was used because the example uses a multidimensional array, but you have an array of objects. So just use `$club->getClub()`. It seems like you're struggling to understand this. I'd advise you to spend some more time learning core PHP before continuing with Symfony.

Comment: I will spend more time learning PHP. Thank you so much for all your help and advices.